# Calculating Capacity in Rally

Tags: rally, capacity

Can anyone explain to me how to calculate your capacity in Rally. I am new to Rally and I am trying to figure out how most of the functions work.

There is a capacity column next to each developer with a pencil where you can type in your capacity. I am assuming it's number of working days in the Sprint * hours of work you are currently assigned or some sort.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

The capacity you find on the Track->Team Status per person is the number of available hours in the selected iteration.

What you need to decide is, how many "productive" hours do each person have per work day.

You can find the help documentation here: https://help.rallydev.com/view-team-member-capacity